# Is there any way how to pass component/html into string in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, string, components, svelte

What I am trying to achieve is to pass component into a string of a variable or some similar solution. I have tried {@html someVariable} but it works for me only in one way it means text from string to HTML. But I need the text from HTML to string. I've tried document.elementById() but always get return 'document is not defined'. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
App.svelte

<script>
import Component from './component.svelte';
import Description  from './description .svelte';


// How to declare component/html into variable?

let test = 'something like <Component /> but acceptable by variable'
let lala = test;

</script>

<Description {test} />
```

```
Description.svelte

<script>
export let lala;
</script>

{#if something}
{@lala html}
{:else if something }
nope
{/if}
```

I think that this question [Rendering Svelte components from HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073094/rendering-svelte-components-from-html-string) has kind of the answer but I failed to make it functional.

Comment: What problem did you face when trying to implement the question you linked to?

Comment: @Smitop I don't know how to create a custom element from a web component. I am using Svelte.Kit and still have the error that customElement:true is missing since Svelte.kit doesn't have rollup.config.js but svelte.config.js without plugin section I am not sure where should I add that line.

Comment: Why you just don't import Component.svelte into Description.svelte and then use it in that if?

Comment: @Jardulino I'm trying to create a universal component that can be used multiple times through the app, only with differences in variables. In your scenario, I would have to copy the whole component many times and have a lot of duplicate code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by "text from HTML to string", but if you want to pass a component to a child component you can pass it as a prop:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte';
    import Description  from './Description.svelte';
</script>

<Description component={Component} />
```

To display a component that is defined in a variable you can use the `<svelte:component>` special element.

```html
<!-- Description.svelte -->
<script>
    export let component;
</script>

{#if component}
    <svelte:component this={component}></svelte:component>
{:else}
    component isn't set
{/if}
```

Here is a [working Svelte REPL Link](https://svelte.dev/repl/1e750d0516c34dc6951b965329f17cc2?version=3.46.4).

If you want to learn more about the `<svelte:component>` special element [check out the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component).

Comment: Thank you Antonio, for your time and solution to both my questions. Your solution with <svelte:component> leads me to the other solution that can help me with this problem.