# How to render custom components within @html?

Tags: svelte

Here is example of what I'm trying to do but as you can see it doesn't really render the component:

https://svelte.dev/repl/22cf0a93cb514d5da54098b50e113cf8?version=3.52.0

```
{@html '<MyComponent>slot content</MyComponent>'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering Svelte components from HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073094/rendering-svelte-components-from-html-string)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because

> The expression should be valid standalone HTML

[Docs on {@html ...}](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-html)